# Saving Tomcat 7 session in MSSQL database

Tags: java, sql-server, session, tomcat7, load-balancing

We're trying to put our Spring application to Tomcat 7 cluster. We have MSSQL2008R2 database and want to use it for saving Tomcat session. We added context.xml to META-INF directory with additional Tomcat settings:

```
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager">
    <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore"
           driverName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
           connectionURL="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://PRIME2008R2:1433/LL_Prod;instance=MSSQL2008R2;"
           connectionName="some_user"
           connectionPassword="some_password"
           sessionTable="tomcat_sessions"
           sessionIdCol="id"
           sessionDataCol="data"
           sessionValidCol="valid"
           sessionMaxInactiveCol="maxinactive"
           sessionLastAccessedCol="lastaccess" />
</Manager>
```

The similar code works fine for MySQL, but we can't install new database or change something in Tomcat settings. Tomcat gives no errors or some useful information. Is it possible to make it works with MSSQL or it works only with MySQL? Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide me the query which you have used for creating the session table in MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

There might be a reason of missing jar for your database connector. As tomcat has mysql connector jar in lib folder. Check for your db connector jar there. If it is there than it could not be any db specific issue.